# Open file to view/manipulate data in browser before sending to server

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible, using a combination of `<input type="file">` and Javascript, to load the contents of a text file into the browser to let the user review the contents and possibly manipulate it, before sending it to the server?

In my case, the file may contain thousands of records and I want the user to be able to confirm and possibly manipulate the contents prior to uploading. I also don't want to have to upload it to the server until the user has verified the data in the browser application.

Comment: I haven't done it, so won't be attempting to answer your question but I do know of the `FileReader` API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: I am just looking at that page, thanks :-D

Comment: Great, it has a few functions like `readAsBinaryString` etc – there is a little article here: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-reading-files. readAsText might let you work through each row if it is a CSV or something like that...